# Сменить ip адрес

Tags: windows, ip, ip-address, netsh

Возможно ли сменить ip адрес в сети интернет с помощью утилиты `netsh`? Пробовал вот такую команду :

> netsh interface ip set address name="MyWeb" static 192.168.10.155
>   255.255.255.0 192.168.10.40 1

где :

static 192.168.10.155(новый ip)

255.255.255.0(маска)

192.168.10.40(префикс подсети)

1 (DHCP разрешен)

После чего интернет соединение выключается и восстановить его можно только вернув старые настройки. И неудивительно ведь `DHCP` сервер выдает `ip` адреса, насколько я понимаю самостоятельно сменить неполучится что бы у 2х пк не было одного адреса. Итак вопрос - можно ли реально сменить ip с помощью `netsh` ?

PS если нельзя в винде то может в линуксе проще ?

UPD Мои настройки через `netsh interface ip show address`

```
Настройка интерфейса "WNC"
DHCP включен:                      Да
IP-адрес                           192.168.0.10
Префикс подсети:                   192.168.0.0/24 (маска 255.255.255.0)
Основной шлюз:                     192.168.0.1
Метрика шлюза:                     0
Метрика интерфейса:                25
```

Comment: Вы лучше добавьте в вопрос вывод ipconfig /all при котором всё работает.

Comment: страный префикс подсети. Либо Вы его взяли со старых настроек (и он не подходит для Вашего нового айпи), либо просто выдумали.

Comment: @KoVadim у команды netsh в этом месте вроде как шлюз по умолчанию указывается, т.ч. автор скорее всего перепутал названия.

Comment: @KoVadim а как префикс подсети зависит от ip ?

Comment: префикс подсети определяет допустимый диапазон айпи. Если Ваш айпи выходит за его пределы, то он просто не будет доступен для работы (говоря по простому - интернета не будет). (да, всегда можно настроить маршруты, но это отдельная большая тема)

Comment: @KoVadim те в моем случае последнее число в ip не должно превышать 40?

Comment: не совсем. Надо знать полностью подсетку с префиксом. Оно выглядит где то так `192.168.1.16/29`. Но в любом случае, зачем Вы меняете айпишник  и кто управляет шлюзом?

Comment: @KoVadim добавил в вопрос конфигурацию сети. не на все сайты можно зайти с моего ip, спасибо РКН. Вопрос про управление шлюзом не понял.

Comment: @de_frag добавил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если очень кратко - netsh ip сменить может, то только толку с этого мало. Более того, в Вашем случае оно никак не поможет в борьбе с РКН.

Подробнее.

192.168.0.1-192.168.0.255  - это диапазон "серых" адресов. Они действительны только в пределах локальной сети. Для Интернета они "невидимы". А видно только внешний адрес маршрутизатора/роутера (в данном случае для Вас роутер имеет адрес 192.168.0.1). А роутер может как иметь внешний апйи, так и входить в другую локальную сеть. Внешний адрес уже поменять часто бывает сильно сложнее, это можно сделать сменой провайдера или просто переподключится (но и это не поможет с РКН).

Что делать? можно использовать proxy/VPN и подобное, но они как бы не совсем законны на территориях действия РКН.

Поможет ли netsh - нет - он меняет не тот адрес. А даже если бы поменять внешний адрес, скорее всего провайдер сильно поругает вначале, а интернета скорее всего не будет.

Надежный способ побороть проблему - выехать из территории, подконтрольной РНК, но как это делать - это уже отдельная история.

Comment: если утилита меняет ip адрес пк в локальной сети то понятно почему каждый веб-сервис по определению ip указывал совсем другой адрес нежели `ipconfig\all`. попытался сменить ip через netsh и пришлось заново ставить настройки DNS и разрешать dhcp, что тоже не привело ни к чему.

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю что мой ip в интернете поставляет провайдер и я мало что могу с ним сделать ?

Comment: да, Ваш айпи определяется провайдером.